# When was a decree issued by the Greeks that forbade speaking God's name?

Tags: greece

This is in follow-up to a question on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73633/does-this-passage-prove-a-greek-source-to-the-prohibition-of-speaking-the-tetrag)

The Babylonian Talmud states:

> ‘**On the third of Tishri the mention [of God] in bonds was abolished: for the Grecian Government had forbidden the mention of God's name** (26) by the Israelites, and when the Government of the Hasmoneans became strong and defeated them, they ordained that they should mention the name of God even on bonds, and they used to write thus: ‘In the year So-and-so of Johanan, High Priest to the Most High God’, and when the Sages heard of it they said, ‘Tomorrow this man will pay his debt and the bond will be thrown on a dunghill’,

I assume the decree from the Greeks preceeded the Hebrew abolition of using God's name in bonds on the third of Tishri.

I would like to know when the Greeks issued their decree.

I wonder where, on the timeline, this prohibition falls in relation to when the Masorites pointed Hebrew Scripture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact year, but it was some year between 175 BC (the ascension of [Antiochius IV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiochus_IV_Epiphanes) to the Selucid throne, and 168 BC, when Antiochus installed an image of the Greek god Zeus in the holy temple.

The result was the [Maccabean Revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maccabean_Revolt) that started in 167 BC. By 160 BC, it had become successful enough to allow the establishment of the Hasmonean dynasty.

Comment: Your linked article actually says 6th century AD, not BC!

Comment: I am talking about the date of the Masoritic text. All scholars put this well into the Christian era.

Comment: @fdb: I deleted the last paragraph to save on discussion and confusion. Will you remove your (presumed) downvote?

Comment: When you answer the question of "when the Masorites pointed the Hebrew Scripture."

Comment: @Fdb: I'll pass on that. Better no answer than a wrong answer or one that I don't fully understand.